# Is There a way to fire KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK to a customized button?

Tags: android

I want to create another back button in my application. To do that I could use the finish method but the Action that I need already exists in Android KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, than I was trying just to fire this event on my clicklistener, there's a way to do that?

Button btnVoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);

```
    btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // HERE I WANT TO USE KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this.  The functionality doesn't exist in the key event. It exists in the finish method which is called by the key event, so just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this override onbackpressed and invoke it on your click

        @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
  btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```